# How to typeset the titlepage and its verso in ConTeXt?

Tags: titles, context

I typeset the titlepage and its verso, but it always generate an empty page on the right if facing. My codes are as follows:

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=stop,
   title=Life in These Days,
   author=Tim Li]
\setupinteractionscreen
  [option=doublesided]

\usetypescript[palatino]
\setupbodyfont[palatino,12pt]

\setuppagenumbering
  [location={footer,middle},
   alternative=doublesided]

\setupmakeup
  [standard]
  [pagestate=start]

\starttext
\startfrontmatter
% titlepage
\startmakeup[standard][doublesided=no]
\vskip2in
\midaligned{\switchtobodyfont[36pt]\bf Life in These Days}
\vfill
\midaligned{\switchtobodyfont[20pt]\bf Tim Li}
\blank[medium]
\midaligned{\switchtobodyfont[20pt]\bf January 11, 2013}
\stopmakeup
% its verso
\startmakeup[standard]
This document was typeset by using \CONTEXT.
\vfill
\stopmakeup
\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter
% 
\stopbodymatter
\stoptext
```

If add `[doubesided=no]` to the first `\startmakeup[standard]` that produce the titlepage, it will produce a page with page number 2 at the right of the titlepage and the verso of this titlepage will be the next page following page 2. That's not what I want.

How to set the options of the `\startmakeup` so that I can typeset the titlepage with its verso just after it. If so, when printing the document, the titlepage and its verso will be presented on the same paper.

---

*Edit:* As Wolfgang said, we should set the makeup as follows

```
\setupmakeup
  [standard]
  [pagestate=start,
   page=yes]

\starttext
\startfrontmatter
\startmakeup[standard][doublesided=no]
% write your titlepage here
\stopmakeup
\startmakup[standard]
% write its verso here
\stopmakeup
% dedication, preface, contents ...
\stopfrontmatter
\startbodypart
% ...
\stopbodypart
\startbackmatter
% ...
\stopbackmatter
\stoptext
```

This is what I want.

Comment: If what Wolfgang says is a working solution, it is better to post it as an answer and self-accept. This way, the question goes off the 'unanswered' list. **NB: Posting an answer to your own question is [explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).**

Comment: @Esteis ok, I will.

Comment: Good-oh. You might as well accept it, too, because I don't think any competing answers are forthcoming. :-)

Comment: @Esteis Ok, now. At that time, I have to wait for another 23 hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Wolfgang's idea. I am only the lucky dog to typeset these codes here.

```
\setupmakeup
  [standard]
  [pagestate=start,
   page=yes]

\starttext
\startfrontmatter
\startmakeup[standard][doublesided=no]
% write your titlepage here
\stopmakeup
\startmakup[standard]
% write its verso here
\stopmakeup
% dedication, preface, contents ...
\stopfrontmatter
\startbodypart
% ...
\stopbodypart
\startbackmatter
% ...
\stopbackmatter
\stoptext
```